# How to make icon clickable

Tags: html

I have some awesome icons that I would like to direct to a link when clicked. I tried wrapping them in anchor tags, but that doesn't work for some reason, what can I do? I tried two implementations.

- First one

```html
    <a href ="Login.php">
        <li class="nav-item border rounded-circle mx-2 cart-icon">
            <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart p-2"></i>
        </li>
    </a>
```

- Second one

```html
    <li class="nav-item border rounded-circle mx-2 cart-icon">
        <a href="Login.php"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart p-2"></i></a>
    </li>
```

Comment: It should work as-is. Maybe, `Login.php` is wrong. Either for the capital letter or the relative path.

Comment: The file name and path is right, it's just not clicking. Quite funny I received a downvote for this question since I know it should be working but it's not

Comment: is there a code snippet so we can try to fix what is wrong?

Comment: The ones I posted above is the only code snippet that involves my question, unless something is wrong with that, I'm not sure where else I can look for the problem and I don't want to post my entire code since it's too long

Comment: The first snippet is wrong, since list items can’t be enclosed in an anchor tag. But the second is correct: I guess you have issues with the CSS styling. I see `rounded-circle` as a class, but Font Awesome needs special classes for rounded buttons: check https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/stacking-icons.

Comment: I tried the second snippet first since after research I saw that's how it was implemented, but since that didn't work I tried the first snippet. None out of the two are working however so I'm baffled as to why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the list, it's not needed

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2442adcce2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
 </head>
 <body>
 <a href ="https://www.w3schools.com">
            <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart p-2"></i>
 </a> 
</body>
</html>
```

This works perfectly, feel free to reply if it doesn't work. I've tested it to make sure.

Comment: It's working now without the list, thank you. I'm confused why it worked without the list though

Comment: No problem! I did think the list was a weird addition to the snippet

Comment: No problem I just did